# "ReferenceError Unknown plugin" when I try to transform js files in a directory using babel cli

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am somewhat new to Babel. I was successful when tried to transform some .jsx files in a directory using this command:

```
babel --plugins transform-react-jsx test.js
```

But when I tried to transform a list of jsx files in a directory, it failed. Here is the command and error message:

```
babel --plugins transform-react-jsx ../public/js/bundle/temp_realtime/ -d ../public/js/bundle/realtime
```

---

```
ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-react-jsx" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "../public/js/bundle/temp_realtime"
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:193:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:173:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:271:36)
    at OptionManager.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:416:10)
    at File.initOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
    at new File (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
    at transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:53:22)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:62:12)
```

---

I have no idea that why it turned out to be like this. Plugin babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx has been installed using command:

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

Comment: Where is the plugin installed? It needs to be in a parent `node_modules` relative to `temp_realtime` so since you're using `..` that seems unlikely.

Comment: It is installed where I called the command, `./`. But I don't want to make the directory `node_modules` be in the same parent directory where `temp_realtime` is in.

Comment: Considering you are new to babel I would suggest to use it via Gulp so you don't have to hassle with all the command line parameters this way. Check out [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) and [Gulp babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I'll try it out : )

Comment: @E. Sundin, it doesn't work..

Answer (score 8):

It happened to me because I was accidentally using:

```
{
  "plugins": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

when I actually meant:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```